# Lazarus Htmlviewer porting to cross platform

Tags: html, lazarus

I´m using Lazarus for Windows to build an application and now I need to port it to Linux and Mac. The problem is that I used the THtmlViewer component , that runs only on Windows (That I discovered only today).

Please, anyone knows of a similar cross platform component. I have a database full of Html notes and I need to handle it. Maybe could be possible to convert HTML to Rich Text. But I have no idea how to use it. 
Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: What version of THtmlViewer you are using? There are at least 2 that I know: form CCR and from [GitHub](https://github.com/BerndGabriel/HtmlViewer) including 5 branches. Also try to use [Turbopower](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Webbrowser#Integrate_web_browser_component_in_application) - it will work surely because it used in the Lazarus IDE.

Comment: Ok. I'm using Turbopower and it's working on Windows and Linux. Thank you so much @Abelisto

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try [THtmlPort](http://wiki.freepascal.org/THtmlPort)

I used it to port my code to lazarus and had to make just a view changes to my code.

Comment: I have tried on Windows and worked like a charm, but unfortunately doesn't worked on lLinux :( Do you have any tip @Alexander Balzer

Comment: What exactly does not work? Have you read http://wiki.freepascal.org/THtmlPort#Status? I had to update my lazarus to 0.9.2.9 and to apply the patch for gtk2 use.